# Healpy default format for lmax

Tags: python, numpy, astronomy, healpy

I found in the Healpy documentation that `healpy.anafast` has a default value for lmax of 3*nside-1

Is there a reason for this standard? Is it a standard within HEALPix, a standard for CMB experiments, or may it has physical reasons?

Edited: When I run `anafast` on a sky map `Nside=4`, the number of Cl values I get is of length = 12. That makes me think that lmax should be `lmax=3Nside`.

However, when using generated Cl values, the first two numbers are equal to zero: the monopole is zero, the dipole is zero.

Therefore, when I set the l values by `np.arange(len(Clvalues))`, should I also remove the terms `[0,1]` for the monopole and dipole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spherical harmonics discretized using HEALPix (either sampled at pixel centers, or avaraged over pixel areas) form a linearly independent system up to lmax = 3 nsmax -1. (from here: [HEALPX anafast](http://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov/html/facilitiesnode7.htm))

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. If I take a map nsmax=4 (Nside=4), and run `anaphase`, I get 12 values for Cl. Doesn't that mean there are 12 value for l, i.e. lmax = 12 = 3*nsmax? Not 3*nsmax-1?

Comment: Well, lmax should be the "Maximum l of the power spectrum". So if you set it to lmax=0 there will be one Cl, namely C0. So if you set it to lmax=11 you'll get 12 numbers, starting from C0, C1 ... C11